# Is there a way to automatically add a photo texture to materials of the same name?

Tags: texturing, materials, import

When using the smd import plugin, http://steamreview.org/BlenderSourceTools/, I am able to import the 3d model with the correct materials, but the materials are all blank. It is tedious to select the texture file in the same folder as the model, assign it to the correct materials, turn on specular color, then repeat for the normal maps, turning off the color and turning off  show alpha and selecting normal map for hundreds of textures.Is there a way to import the files so that the material is assigned the correct textures or a plugin to assign textures to materials en masse?

Comment: Welcome MikeLitorus :) Since this Addon is open source, might be better reporting the issue or submit a feature request on github: https://github.com/Artfunkel/BlenderSourceTools. Anyway, enjoy blender.se!